# Websocket frequentry disconnected

Tags: websocket

I'm constructing a website using websocket.
It seems good when it's connected by a few users. But once number of connections reaches around 100, users get many disconnect.

It seems not to be caused by lacking of file descriptor max, because our server's file descriptor max is thousands times of opening files.
And timeout seems unlikely to be the cause. Because each users get access with websocket for each 10 seconds.

Does anyone hit other reasons of the disconnect?

I'm not good at English and maybe this post is difficult to understand, excuse me.

Using Browsers: Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari. No differences between them.